# Auditing Microsoft Authenticator usage across Azure

Tags: two-factor-authentication

I'm pushing for Microsoft Authenticator adoption across my Azure tenant.  How can I definitively find out who's already installed and recently used Microsoft Authenticator ?

One not very effective way is for me to download all registered devices and filter out all the Windows devices.

Comment: How are you pushing this out? Intune? Some other MDM?

Comment: Thanks, after getting my act together enough to ask the question, I realized the answer was right underneath the settings I was already making.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was right under the configurations I'd already made.

In Azure, within the tenant, within Protection->Authentication Methods where I'd already set up Policies and Settings, look at User Registration Details.  Filter by Methods Registered, and look only for the Microsoft Authenticator options.

This expanding list will let me know who's signing up over time.